# Can't apt update after deleting proxy

Tags: ubuntu, apt, proxy, apt-cacher

I had an apt cache server installed in `192.168.40.97:3142` using `apt-cacher-ng`. To use it on my laptop I added a file `02proxy` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory which had the following content.

`Acquire::http { Proxy "http://192.168.40.97:3142"; };`

But then I wanted to use apt without proxy as the server had some issues. So I deleted the `02proxy` file and tried `apt update`. But its still trying to connect to the server.

```
r2m@ssl-60:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.40.97:3142 (192.168.40.97). - connect (111:     Connection refused)
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.40.97:3142:
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.40.97:3142:
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not connect to 192.168.40.97:3142 (192.168.40.97). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Reading package lists... Done                   
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
6 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 192.168.40.97:3142 (192.168.40.97). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.40.97:3142:
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to 192.168.40.97:3142:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not connect to 192.168.40.97:3142 (192.168.40.97). - connect  (111: Connection refused)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What should be done to remove the proxy?
I'm using it on Ubuntu 16.04

`Linux ssl-60 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: My suspicion is that a reboot would fix this, but there is probably an easier way.

Comment: Reboot didn't help

Comment: You may have configured the proxy somewhere else.

Comment: I don't remember adding any configuration anywhere else. If I did, do you know where it could've been done?

Comment: it has to be under /etc/apt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if there is a line containing the word `Proxy` in this file
`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf`

and if the word `Proxy` is present, delete the line and after run the command `apt update`

source: https://wiki.debian.org/AptConf

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want `apt-get` to use a proxy,
use `apt-get` as:

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy=false <update/install>
```